# Django custom manager filter query set (by parameter)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like my models to automatically filter by current user.

I did this by defining:

```
class UserFilterManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(UserFilterManager, self).get_queryset().filter( owner=get_current_user() )
```

where `get_current_user()` is a middleware which extracts the current user from the `request` passed to Django.

However, I need to use the models from Celery which does not go through the middleware. In these cases

`MyModel.objects.all()`

needs to become

`MyModel.objects.filter(user=<some user>)`

To avoid wrong queries caused by forgetting to filter by user, I would like the model/manager/queryset to assert when a query (any query) is performed without a filter on `user`.

Is there a way to achieve this?
From what I see `get_queryset()` cannot receive parameters and `models.QuerySet` won't provide aid here.

Comment: This feels kinda weird to me. Why are you trying to twist the default when you can simply remind yourself to do filter(user=<someuser>)

Comment: Two reasons: (1) anything that becomes repetitive is prone to mistakes; (2) I now have a second filter that needs to be applied to most (not all) of my models which increases the chance of a mistake