# Safest and driest way to filter query_set depending on some user info

Tags: django, django-models, django-middleware

I have a Post model with a boolean field, is_draft. If the user is logged and is member of the staff, then I want to displays all posts; otherwise, only the posts for which is_draft is false.

My first thought was to use a custom model manager and use request.user as following:

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self):
    if request.user and request.user.is_staff:
        return super().get_queryset()
    else:
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_draft=False)
```

but request is not available in the model.

I saw some people use a [middleware to access the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747344/django-custom-manager-filter-query-set-by-parameter) in the model. It seems to me the safest way to address my need (ie it's done once, in the custom manager; people modifying the views.py don't have to bother, no risk of forgetting it) but this solution seems controversial.

I have of course the possibility to add some logic in the view, but I feel this is not DRY (as I query Post many times) nor safe (risk somebody forgets it at some point).

According to you, what would be the cleanest and safest way to address this need?

PS: I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039448/limiting-access-to-objects-in-django) for which a solution was proposed for Class-based views, but my views are function-based.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Filter them in the View. You cannot filter them in the models.py

Comment: In addition to filtering in the view, I think it would be a good idea to instead of using a boolean indicating status, you should use a status field with choices instead. My thoughts behind this are basically that a post can be in draft, published, review status and would likely be so exclusively. Just a thought...

Comment: Thanks @MaharshiBingumalla! My understanding is that your code would show to a user the posts he created. What I'm trying to do is different: I want a user which is not part of the staff to see all Posts, created by any user, that are not a draft; and for staff member, all Posts, including drafts, created by any user. Would you have any idea how to address that? Thanks!

Comment: @gibbe75 I get it. Edited my solution. Check it once.

Comment: @Maharshi, it works, thanks! The only issue I see with this solution is that qs = Post.objects.all() still return all posts, including is_draft=True, for any user. I feel there is a risk that at some point, somebody forget to use get_posts(request.user) and use all(). But I guess unless I choose to go with the middleware solution, I need to live with this risk. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with a custom function in the manager.

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):

     def get_posts(self, user):
          if user.is_staff:
               return super().get_queryset()
          else:
               return super().get_queryset().filter(is_draft=False)
```

And in your View, get the queryset using:

```
qs = Post.objects.get_posts(request.user)
```